# How can we set a custom show animation to FlatList item in React Native during rendering?

Tags: animation, react-native

As the title saying, I want set a animation to FlatList item when the FlatList renders. In Android, I can use `LayouAnimation`,then set `android:layoutAnimation` property to `ListView`, then every item will be shown with the custom animation.So how can we achieve this like in Android.
Any solution?

Edit:For example, these items will be shown from left to right in order, or from bottom to top with opacity.More importantly, they are one by one instead of together.